# VSTS Agent Check if VM Already in Release Environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, powershell-dsc

I'm trying to use Powershell DSC to provision virtual machines in Azure and use Azure DevOps to manage the actually code deployment onto the virtual machines.  The DSC script is setup to install IIS, asp.net core hosting, setup the sites in IIS, but not actually deploy any application code.  The last step in the DSC is to add the virtual machine to azure devops.  I went into the Environments tab in devops and copied the powershell script provided, parameterized my PAT so it could be passed into the configuration script, and executed.  However, when the script runs a second time, it gives an error because the a resource already exists with the same name in that environment.  I could not find a way to check if the VM was already registered as an environment resource in devops using the vsts agent config.  I'm considering using the --replace flag, but I don't know if that will lose my deployment history or has any other consequences.

**Is there a way to check if a Virtual Machine is already registered as a resource in an Azure DevOps environment.**